# SwiftUI Views are deallocated before the async call returns

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list of users in a navigation stack, each item wrapped by a navigation link.

```
struct UserListView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.users) { user in
                    NavigationLink(value: user.id) {
                        Text(user.givenName)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("UserList")
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self, destination: { id in
                FormView(id: id) // gets called multiple times, 2 times in my experience
            })
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.findAll()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in the `FormView` that gets `init` multiple times, and as a result, the same for it's associated `viewModel`, and as I call fetch department list from the network layer, by the time the result comes back, the caller (`viewModel`) is already gone (`deinit`).

```
struct UserFormView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = FormViewModel()
    
    @State var first: String = ""
    @State var last: String = ""
    @State var department: Department? = nil
    
    var id: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("First", text: $first)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                              
                TextField("Last", text: $last)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .font(.system(size: 16))
            }

            HStack {
                Picker(selection: $department, label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.departments, id: \.self) { department in
                        Text(department.name ?? "").tag(department)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("User Form")
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.findAllDepartments()
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my ObservableObject that gets no chance to update the departments, because this object gets deinit before that.

I could tell from the print statement in the init and deinit as they come and go multiple times.

```
class FormViewModel: ObservableObject {
 
    @Published var user: User? = nil
    
    @Published var departments: [Department] = []
    
    private var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    private var rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(10)) + 1
    
    init() {
        print("init \(rand)") // gets called multiple times
    }

    
    func findAllDepartments() {
        delegate?.findAllDepartments()
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: {[weak self] completion in
                switch completion{
                case .finished:
                    print("finished")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self] departments in
                self?.departments.append(contentsOf: departments) // no chance, it's deallocated already
                self?.objectWillChange.send()
            })
            .store(in: &cancellable)
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit \(rand)") // multiple times
    }
}
```

Question: I understand it's perhaps the nature of the SwiftUI to create and re-recreate Views as state changes, but how can we be consistent then?

Comment: You shouldn't ever be using `@ObservedObject` where you own the object. It should be `@StateObject`. `@StateObject` prevents the object from getting recreated on each render.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app

Comment: @jnpdx I see, so I just remove `ObservedObject` from `@ObservedObject private var viewModel = FormViewModel()`, ? and use `@@StateObject private var viewModel = FormViewModel()`

Comment: Replace `@ObservedObject` with `@StateObject`

Comment: thanks, I guess i was following some old references. @loremipsum

Comment: Just to clarify, all this multiple `init` and `deinit`, can I safely ignore them? Is this normal?

Comment: On a `View`, yes -- expect to see many `init` calls. On an `ObservableObject`, no -- expect to see one for the lifetime of the view/object. That's why I'm suggesting you use `@StateObject`. Agree with @loremipsum that you should check out some modern documentation to help understand the system. This pattern changed in SwiftUI 2.

Comment: makes sense, i understand @StateObject will keep the single instance for reuse, however, i still see multiple `init/deinit` going on for the `FormViewModel`, and its because `FormView(id: id)` gets called twice in the `navigationDestination ` (using `StateObject` for both of my viewModels)

Comment: Mind advising on the `navigationDestination`, i get my breakpoint hit there twice once i tap on the list item.